# IOS warning: Unable to allocate render buffer storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, buffer, xcode6, statusbar

I have a simple IOS app. It include two toolbars and map view. I use default libraries only (no cocoa or etc.).

When I debug my app on real IPhone5s (IOS8.1), I got "Unable to allocate render buffer storage! 0x1741f2c00" in my console when IPhone change orientation (No problem with simulator). And status bar disappear when it turn to landscape and return when it is portrait on real device and simulator (It's my general problem).

App subscribe to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

But text appear in console and status bar disappear independently of calling

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{

}
```

Google don't help me. All links connected to cocoa library error or some graphics methods I don't use.

Comment: I've found this problem only seems to happen with MKMapView when changing orientations. The tool bars or subviews in the map view have no impact. On the up side, the warning doesn't seem to have any negative effects on the app other than being annoying.

Comment: Agree with guthook, seems to only happen with mapView rotations.

Comment: Is it an opengl app? or spritekit? or?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I'm also seeing this when animating the mapView's frame.

Comment: The issue is unsolved, but not critical.

Comment: Have you ever able to solved this? @WantToKnow

Comment: @Pooja No, it was just annoying message that has no impact on app performance. At least it seemed so. Maybe an Xcode bug.

Answer (score -1):

You may be using constraints. If so, you need to remove them (in the `viewDidLoad` if you don't want to touch your storyboard/xib) and then set them in the `willRotate`.

Also another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014770/map-rotation-horribly-slow-on-ios8) seems to solve it this way.